# No password for a Windows 8 user account

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I don't want a password for my normal user account. The only way I have found to no require one is by using `netplwiz` and un-checking "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer." Problem is, I still want the administrator account to require a password. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: using a password, but bypassing it is as secure as no password at all, so would not using a password at all for account suffice?

Comment: I don't want my account to have a password (and since it has no privileges, it shouldn't matter). But I want my administrative account to require a password, because it has all the privileges.

Comment: @SylvestertheCat: He wants no password for the non-admin accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unchecking that checkbox is fine.

If you uncheck that checkbox, it will ask you for the password of a default account to log in as.
When you turn on the computer, it will automatically log in to that account using the password you enter.
All other users will still require passwords.

Alternatively, you could just remove that user's password.

Comment: How do you remove a password for a user in windows 8? it isn't a local account, its one of those MS accounts. Not sure if I want that either honestly.

Comment: From what I gather, I have to make the account local to remove the password, is that true? (I already did it, just not sure if it **has** to be local to have no password)

Answer (score 2):

At the start screen type

> account password

then highlight "settings" on right side, then click/select "user accounts" icon.

.
[image]